# Java ArrayList type issue

Tags: java

I am new in Java.
Now I want to generate an ArrayList containing some values.

```
"Circle","blue","red","yellow","1","2","3","4"
```

How can I code this. I found some tutorial from internet. Only int or string accepted? How about mix? Could someone should me the code that how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList(); 
al.add("Circle"); 
al.add("blue"); 
al.add("red"); 
al.add("yellow"); 
al.add("1"); 
al.add("2"); 
al.add("3"); 
al.add("4");
```

here is a simple tutorial http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=234

or you can do this as well

```
String[] words = {"Circle", "blue", "red", "yellow", "1", "2", "3", "4"};  

List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Circle", "blue", "red", "yellow", "1", "2", "3", "4");
```

If you want to mix types, you'd need a `List<Object>`, and to remove the `""` around the numbers. The example you show is all strings.

Once you start mixing types, you need to check the type when you're consuming the list, which may or may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
t.add("string");
t.add(5);
```

Or

```
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList("string", 5);
```

Or

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>()
{{
     add("string");
     add(5);
}};
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have one type for one list, some code for creating a list containing only Strings could be:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  
//add my text as the first element
list.add("my text");
```

For a list with only ints you would have Integer instead of String in the example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store `"1","2","3","4"`  as string you could use

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll("Circle","blue","red","yellow","1","2","3","4");
```

You can not store `int` in any collection.However If you want to store `"1","2","3","4"`  as Integer along with strings you could use

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
Collections.addAll("Circle","blue","red","yellow",1,2,3,4);
```

Autoboxing will takecare of converting `int` to `Integer`

You many need to be extra careful while using `ArrayList<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, it's not recommended (although it's possible) to mix different types in a list of objects. So, for storing a list of Strings you would do this:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And then add them:

```
stringList.add("Circle");
stringList.add("blue");
stringList.add("red");
stringList.add("yellow");
stringList.add("1");
stringList.add("2");
stringList.add("3");
stringList.add("4");
```